# 2D Vertical/Horizontal collision detection

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection

I'm writing a 2D platformer in Java, and I've run into a problem. I have two objects: Both have bounding boxes, and four coordinates to represent the corners of the boxes.

My issue is that I am trying to find a way to simulate collision, but I just can't seem to do it. I've tried searching all over the place, but most sites just demonstrate OpenGL tactics.

Let us represent the bounding box coordinates like so:

TL: Top-left
TR: Top-right
BL: Bottom-left
BR: Bottom-right

Here is how I originally proposed testing collision:

```
if(TL1 > TL2 && TL1 < TR2) //X-axis
    //Collision happened, TL1 corner is inside of second object
else if(BL1 < TL2 && BL1 > BL2) //Y-axis
    //Collision happened, BL1 corner is inside of second object
```

This is a very crude way of showing it, but basically I'm checking to see if a corner intersects the other object. The problem is, it doesn't account for both axii. That is to say, an x-collision will occur even if one object is above the other.

If I check for collision on both axii, then there is no way of telling whether it was a horizontal or vertical collision. Or maybe there is and I haven't figured it out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: First check if it collides with the bounding box (on either axis), then check what axis the collision occured at (simple geometry of squares, draw it on paper).

Comment: Well yes, but the trouble is it 'technically' needs to collide on both axii in order for it to be a true collision. I just can't think of a way to determine which axis the collision 'took place on', as in which axis object A was moving along, if that makes sense.

Comment: I suggest interpolation then, don't let objects move into eachother but instead check if their new position will make them collide. Looking at the sign of their velocity (or delta position) you can see along which axis the object was moving. This will tell you at what axis the collision will occur, you can then handle the collision as you like.

Comment: Yes, I think that makes sense. I was designing a method to test 'collision' independently without any information about an object moving. I'll do it that way, testing collision from the perspective of the moving object.

Comment: When I made a pong game on my TI-83 graphing calculator, interpolation was the way to go. First check the space the object is attempting to move into for a collision. If it can move, then move, else, handle collision. Checking intersection _after_ the collision gives no valuable information to handle the collision. As @arynaq states, interpolation allows you to use the object's movement axii to handle collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is from java.awt.Rectangle.

you should be able to modify it to suit the coords you have.

```
/**
 * Determines whether or not this <code>Rectangle</code> and the specified
 * <code>Rectangle</code> intersect. Two rectangles intersect if
 * their intersection is nonempty.
 *
 * @param r the specified <code>Rectangle</code>
 * @return    <code>true</code> if the specified <code>Rectangle</code>
 *            and this <code>Rectangle</code> intersect;
 *            <code>false</code> otherwise.
 */
public boolean intersects(Rectangle r) {
    int tw = this.width;
    int th = this.height;
    int rw = r.width;
    int rh = r.height;
    if (rw <= 0 || rh <= 0 || tw <= 0 || th <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int tx = this.x;
    int ty = this.y;
    int rx = r.x;
    int ry = r.y;
    rw += rx;
    rh += ry;
    tw += tx;
    th += ty;
    //      overflow || intersect
    return ((rw < rx || rw > tx) &&
            (rh < ry || rh > ty) &&
            (tw < tx || tw > rx) &&
            (th < ty || th > ry));
}
```